# Github Actions Pytest fail process along with saving it to txt file

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions, pytest-cov

I am trying to set up workflow, which runs tests and comments test coverage. To achieve that, I need to save pytest call results into txt file. However, by doing so with following command:

`Run pytest --cov=./ --junitxml=pytest.xml --capture=tee-sys --cov-report=term-missing:skip-covered tests/test_app.py | tee pytest-coverage.txt`

I run into a problem, when if some tests fail whole workflow finishes anyway. What I want is workflow failing if any of the tests fail, otherwise I will use pytest-coverage.txt to print code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to set `pipefail`:

> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) > command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the
> pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by default.

So the workflow step should be:

```yaml
run: |
  set -o pipefail
  pytest --cov=./ \
         --junitxml=pytest.xml \
         --capture=tee-sys \
         --cov-report=term-missing:skip-covered \
         tests/test_app.py | \
  tee pytest-coverage.txt
```

**Notes:**

- In cloud runners this shouldn't be necessary but it seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/353) in self-hosted runners.
- Alternatively it could also be set by modifying `shell` in [job defaults](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/setting-default-values-for-jobs).